# Authentication object loss into ClientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId() method for WebClient with oauth2 filters

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, webclient

In a multi-tenancy Spring boot web app (with spring security 5), I need to make http requests to externals services secured by oauth2.

**Each client using the same app can has multiple oauth2 config depending on external services it can access.**

There is how I instantiate my singleton WebClient:

```
OAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = OAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                .clientCredentials()
                .build();
                
OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository = new HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository();

// oAuth2ClientRegistrationDAO is my custom bean implements ClientRegistrationRepository defined below
DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(oAuth2ClientRegistrationDAO, oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository);
authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);

ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction filter = new ServletOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                authorizedClientManager);

// WebClient to be used to communicate thought oauth2 secured webservices               
WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().apply(filter.oauth2Configuration()).build();
```

This is my custom bean implements ClientRegistrationRepository used to provide right Oauth2 parameters depending on registrationId value:

```
@Repository
public class OAuth2ClientRegistrationDAO implements ClientRegistrationRepository {

    @Override
    public ClientRegistration findByRegistrationId(String registrationId) {
    
        // Problem: auth object is NULL! 
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    
        System.out.println(auth); // print: null
    
        // TODO get ClientRegistration from right database
        // (depending logged tenant, fetched from Authentication object) and return them
    }
}
```

**The problem is when I do a request like this:**

```
// Here, auth is not null: Ok!
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

webClient.get()
    .uri("[External webservice url secured with oauth2]")
    .attributes(
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction
              .clientRegistrationId("[registrationId]"))
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToMono(String.class)
    .block();
```

My Authentication object of logged user is null into OAuth2ClientRegistrationDAO **because on asynchronous implementation of WebClient, method findByRegistrationId() is called on another thread than this used by Authenticated spring app client**.

Edit: I found a potential solution using `SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);` Authentication context is still present on other thread with this configuration